# HTML, CSS - classes , Editors

Tags: html, css, editor

I  have a project with 1 css file and a lot of templates (.tpl), so I know that in my css file there are a lot of classes which I don't use . How can I find these classes?

Is there an editor, plugin or other way, without searching each class in the whole project?

Comment: Do you really mean "classes"? Or the more general "selectors"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is another add-on from sitepoint that finds unused selectors

http://www.sitepoint.com/dustmeselectors/

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is a kind of code coverage tool for CSS, like:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/10704

Comment: I need to open All pages from Project ??? And this addon isn't compatible with firefox 3.5.1

I'll try to downgrade my firefox ... 

thank you this is a good plugin!

Answer (score 0):

http://css-discuss.incutio.com/?page=CssEditors

http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/html_css_editor.html

Answer (score 0):

**Long Method**

This method uses a feature that I know is available in Eclipse, the multi-language IDE. Take each class and search for eat in the project. If there is only one match (the css file, you can safely remove the class) else keep the class in the css file.

Answer (score 0):

Try [CSS Brush](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/css-brush/mamnhhinmmdpcipjnhflillmhnogoobj?hl=en-US), a chrome plugin for creating CSS live. many features like select from page, use complete CSS path or filter to shorten the selector. Context-sensitive-menu and many more features.